# Where can i find .css which was used in vscode?

Tags: css, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, vscode-debugger

I am trying to develop a vscode extension, and to fit with the style of vscode, i am trying to find the same styles (.css) which vscode used to develop.

Ps. Thanks

Comment: where in the GUI do you need to do this? In Webview's it is already injected, you have the Theme colors by name, use the Dev Tools

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Visual Studio Code is **Open Source**, so the source code is on github.
https://github.com/microsoft/vscode

However, creating it yourself can be easier for you.
There are *a lot* of files there and they are very complicated.
It will probably be hard to use that exact css.